# Updating zoom parameters in onTouchEvent ImageView class that hosts a drawable

Tags: android, matrix, imageview, drawable, touch-event

I was able to use a class created by one of the StackOverflow users for my needs.
The class was working fine, but It did not include scrolling(vertically, horizontally). I **modified the following class by including the code** under MotionEvent.Action_Up , which now provides scrolling both horizontally and vertically. ***The main problem*** I am having is with the ZOOM mode.

If you look closely, **Zoom mode happens on** MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
The logic is that it calculates the distance between two fingers and figures out the midpoint between them on the midpoint method. The center of the Zoom must be this midpoint. The code under MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN takes care of 
saving and scaling the matrix.

This class is an ImageView and it hosts a drawable graph. The graph draws nicely and the horizontal and vertical scrolling are now enabled, but the zoom is causing problems: When the drawable loads and I try zooming it works fine, but if I try scrolling after that, the drawable gets lost in the view. Likewise, when I scroll at first and then Zoom, the drawable gets lost in the view very fast. It seems like the matrix changes the ImageView coordinates and therefore the midpoint is not the one that I need as the origin of the zoom.

Inside the drawable class onDraw() I implement the following logic:

```
canvas.save();

    GraphImage.translateX = GraphImage.translateX + MainActivity.keeper14;
    GraphImage.translateY = GraphImage.translateY + MainActivity.keeper15;

    canvas.translate(GraphImage.translateX, GraphImage.translateY);
    canvas.scale(GraphImage.main_scale, GraphImage.main_scale, MainActivity.middy.x , MainActivity.middy.y);

//do my draw calls here

MainActivity.keeper14 = GraphImage.translateX;
MainActivity.keeper15 = GraphImage.translateY;

canvas.restore();
```

As you can see, I use values updated inside the ImageView onTouch method. 
I think the problem might be that the matrix is not coordinating well with the 
canvas.scale()  and canvas.translate() calls.

Here is the ImageView class. By the way, what is the purpose of the matrix in this class. Does it work only on the ImageView or also on the drawable that it has? Also, I use a scaleType = Matrix for this view.

```
public class GraphImage extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {

Paint paint;
Context c;
int color;
Matrix matrix;
Matrix savedMatrix;
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;
static PointF start,mid;
float oldDist;
static float main_scale;
static float translateX,translateY;
String savedItemClicked;
String TAG = "Batman";
float mx , my, curX, curY;


public GraphImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context,attrs);
    //all the variables are init here
    setFocusable(true);

}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    dumpEvent(event);

    // Handle touch events here...
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mx = event.getX();
            my = event.getY();
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
            mode = DRAG;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            oldDist = spacing(event);
            Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
            if (oldDist > 10f) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midPoint(MainActivity.middy, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            curX = event.getX();
            curY = event.getY();
            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            matrix.postTranslate(curX - mx, curY - my);
            translateX = curX - mx;//event.getX() - start.x;
            translateY = curY - my;//event.getY() - start.y;
            this.invalidateDrawable(this.getDrawable());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = NONE;
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mode == DRAG) {                   

                // ...
                /*
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY()
                        - start.y);
                translateX = event.getX() - start.x;
                        translateY = event.getY() - start.y;
                                this.invalidateDrawable(this.getDrawable());
                                */

            } else
            if (mode == ZOOM) {
                float newDist = spacing(event);
                Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                if (newDist > 10f) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                    main_scale = scale;
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, MainActivity.middy.x, MainActivity.middy.y);
                    this.invalidateDrawable(this.getDrawable());
                }

            }

            break;

    }

    this.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    //invalidate();
    return true;
}

/** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);// Math.abs(event.getX() - mx);//event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);//Math.abs(event.getY() - my);//event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return  (float)Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

/** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);//mx + event.getX();//event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);//
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);//my + event.getY();//event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    MainActivity.middy = point;
}

private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",
            "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int action = event.getAction();
    int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
    if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
            || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
        sb.append("(pid ").append(
                action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
        sb.append(")");
    }
    sb.append("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
        sb.append("#").append(i);
        sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
        sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
        sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
        if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
            sb.append(";");
    }
    sb.append("]");
    Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
}
```

}

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I added a few static variables on MainActivity class: translationXX, translationYY , drawing__scale. 
Whenever ACTION_UP came up, I updated translationXX and translationYY, as such:

```
translationXX = translationXX + (curX - mx); //Likewise for translationYY
```

To coordinate with the changes that occurred whenever the drawable was invalidated:

```
canvas.translate(MainActivity.translationXX , MainActivity.translationYY);// inside onDraw of the drawable
```

Likewise, for zoom: Instead of MainActivity.middy as the midpoint of the finger placement on the screen that signified a zoom gesture, I went back to the variable static "mid" defined on GraphImage class. It happened that Mainactivity.middy kept the 
old values assigned to it when the mode was ZOOM. Therefore, the zoom was really not doing good things. Inside the method midpoint of the GraphImage class I replaced the following line:

```
MainActivity.middy = point;
```

with the line:

```
mid = point;
```

To coordinate the zoom  changes that took place inside GraphImage, inside my drawable class onDraw method I scaled the canvas, as such:

```
canvas.scale(MainActivity.drawing_scale, MainActivity.drawing_scale, GraphImage.mid.x,GraphImage.mid.y);//MainActivity.drawing_scale was updated when the mode was ZOOM inside the onTouch method of GraphImage
```

Also, inside ACTION_POINTER_UP: I had to invalidate the drawable since without this
the drawable would zoom as ACTION_MOVE was being called but then, it went back to its previous non-zoom state as soon as the fingers stopped touching the screen.

inside ACTION_POINTER_UP:

```
MainActivity.middy = mid; //this line was called on ACTION_MOVE  when the mode = ZOOM

matrix.postScale(MainActivity.drawing_scale, MainActivity.drawing_scale,MainActivity.middy.x,MainActivity.middy.y)//middy was updated with the latest midpoint "mid" on a previous called to ZOOM inside ACTION_MOVE
```

After this line we simply call invalidate on the drawable. Also, I created a Boolean called moveit = false inside the onTouch(). Whenever ZOOM mode was on, moveit = true
Whenever ACTION_UP was called it would excute the code needed for the translation of the drawable only if(!moveit){//code that translates drawable}
 This changes provide an acceptable view that zooms and scrolls in all directions. I might need to use the onFling() of the GestureDetector class to make it feel more realistic but it works very well. I avoided the nested scrolling (vertical and horizontal). But, I still will like to learn more about the details on using a matrix.